# Nvidia NVML undefined symbol: nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses_v3

Tags: nvidia, mvcc, nvml

./nvml_lib: symbol lookup error: ./nvml_lib: undefined symbol: nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses_v3

```
    nvcc --version
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
    Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
    Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0

    Device Driver Version: 470.141.03
    NVML Version: 11.470.141.03
    Unbuntu 18.04
```

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <nvml.h>

    int
    main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    int i;

    unsigned int deviceCount;
    nvmlReturn_t result;
    char version[64], pname[256];
    nvmlProcessInfo_t infos[32];
    nvmlDevice_t device;
    unsigned int infoCount;

    if ((result = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex_v2(0, &device)) !=  NVML_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex_v2 %d\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((result = nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses_v3(device, &infoCount, infos)) != NVML_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: Get Compute Running Processes error: d\n", result);
        return 1;
    }
    }
```

Replacing "_v3" with "_v2" produces a compiler error. Removing the "_v3" gives the same run time error.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses_v3 is unavailable with Device Driver Version 470.141.03. Switch to the oldest version of nvcc that supports CUDA 11, and was able to compile and link using the older "_v2" call.

```
    nvcc --version
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
    Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
    Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0


    nm --dynamic /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.1 | grep -i runningprocess
    0000000000050e10 T nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses
    0000000000051010 T nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses_v2
    0000000000051370 T nvmlDeviceGetGraphicsRunningProcesses
    0000000000051570 T nvmlDeviceGetGraphicsRunningProcesses_v2
    00000000000518d0 T nvmlDeviceGetMPSComputeRunningProcesses
    0000000000051ad0 T nvmlDeviceGetMPSComputeRunningProcesses_v2
```